# Circular Linked List in Cocoa

Tags: arrays, cocoa, data-structures, circular-list

Is there something similar to a circular linked list available in Cocoa?

I know that an NSArray is ordered - but I don't think I can use 'nextItem' or 'previousItem' - correct?  Furthermore, I need the nextItem of the last item to be the first item.

I could add my own nextItem and previousItem methods, but I'm surprised if Apple haven't implemented something suitable already.  I can't find it though if they have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you can certainly use a category to add the behavior to `NSArray` (as @darren suggests), it's possible that you might actually need a true circular buffer.  If that's the case, check out the [CHDataStructures](http://cocoaheads.byu.edu/wiki/chdatastructures) framework.  Besides a [CHCircularBufferStack](http://dysart.cs.byu.edu/CHDataStructures/interface_c_h_circular_buffer_stack.html), there's also a [CHCircularBufferQueue](http://dysart.cs.byu.edu/CHDataStructures/interface_c_h_circular_buffer_queue.html) and a [CHCircularBufferDeque](http://dysart.cs.byu.edu/CHDataStructures/interface_c_h_circular_buffer_deque.html).

Comment: Is it possible to bind an NSArray to a CHData Structure?  If so, it's definitely worth looking into them.

Comment: I haven't explicitly coded for such behavior, so if you can't, it's not yet supported. However, I've been planning to transform the abstract circular buffer parent class into a subclass of NSMutableArray, which would probably provide some of this functionality for free. (Free to you, not me as the author...)

Comment: Also, note that my circular buffer is not exactly a first-points-to-last (and vice versa) structure. It's basically a wrapped C array where the true index is abstracted from the user. The intent is to make it cheap to insert and remove at either end, since that's what you do most with a stack/queue/deque. Perhaps modifying my doubly-linked list could provide the exact behavior you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any such circular list data structure.  Your idea about implementing it manually seems like a good idea.  I would use a category:

```
@implementation NSArray (myCircularList)

-(id)nextItem;
-(id)previousItem;
```